# Using Windows Powershell, how can I find all files that contain a similar title, one that starts with the same word?

Tags: regex, string, powershell-4.0

I have many pdf files, but I want to delete all the files that begin with the word 'Script'? I tried `^Script"-"[azAZ].pdf` for example.

There can be various names, but the files will always start with the word 'Script' followed by a hyphen '-'. What would be the best way to search for all of these files so I can delete them using Get-Child?

`Get-ChildItem ^Script'-'[azAZ].pdf` was my first thought. I was able to find some of what I was looking for using

```
Get-ChildItem Script*.*
```

What would be the correct way, or more professional way of doing it? Is this the best way?

Comment: What's wrong with simply `Get-ChildIten Script*.pdf` ?

Comment: I was thinking that there was a better way. I did not want to look too unprofessional. I am just starting out myself and wanted to look good and not appear lazy. 
I know I would not use a * when writing a proper SQL query. I thought it was the same thing here with Powershell. Thank you!

Comment: Using `*` as a wildcard which substitutes the variable part of your filenames is absolutely fine and adheres to [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) and that's what makes you a professional: Getting things done with the right set of tools. `SELECT *` is a totally different thing - in terms of your task at hand it would mean `gci *.*` and the inspect each file if its name begins with `Script` and has the `pdf` extension which of course would be awkward. Rule of thumb: If you feel writing to much code your heading the wrong way.

Comment: Thank you very much! That makes sense. I really appreciate it very much.